# How to use text file image URL in html page to show image?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, text-files

I have a text file in which i have about 20+ URL's of images I want to use all these URL's of text file and show images in web browser using python?

Comment: And what is a problem ? Show in question your code and FULL error message.

Comment: put urls in `<img src="...">` and you will have HTML. Probably you could  do it with find/replace in normal editor.

Comment: or use `open()`, `read()`, `split()` to get data from file and later `write()` to save all urls as `<img src="...">`

Comment: I think there is no need of code, i want to open images in html browser i have urls but do not know how to open that urls multiple time

Comment: generate HTML file with all links and open this file in browser.

Comment: or use `webbrowse.open()` to open every url in browser. Or use `Selenium` to control web browser.

Comment: @furas i have a html file. In which only one tag. Of <img src= ''> want to replace '' with 20 urls and show all urls images

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 2.7  :

You need to create html file!

```
f = open("images.txt","r") #all url images

images = f.readlines()

some_file = open("all_images.html","w")

for i in range(0,len(images)):

    some_file.write(str("<img src = "+images[i]+">"+"\n"))

some_file.close()
f.close()
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: No, it is not helpful, i want to open all images on a single page